# String.prototype function will not be added to the String type

Tags: typescript, string, function, prototype

I have an String.extensions.ts file like this:

```
interface String {
   replaceAll(a: string, b: string): string;
   replaceLast(a: string, b: string): string;
}

String.prototype.replaceAll = function (a: string, b: string) {
   let newString = this;
   while (this.includes(a)) {
      newString = newString.replace(a, b);
   }

   return newString.toString();
};

String.prototype.replaceLast = function (a: string, b: string) {
   let stringArray: string[] = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      stringArray.push(this.substring(i, i + 1));
   }

   stringArray[stringArray.lastIndexOf(a)] = b;

   return stringArray.join("");
};
```

My problem is that for some reason the replaceAll function is getting added to the string type but the replaceLast function will not. Inside vscode, I can even select the replaceLast function due to the intellisense, but the output during the production will show:

> rejected promise not handled within 1 second: TypeError: contributes.replaceLast is not a function
> c:\Users\damien.arriens\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:89
> stack trace: TypeError: contributes.replaceLast is not a function

Does somebody have a reason for this?

Comment: 1. Is `contributes` a string? 2. Pretty much always it's a bad idea to redefine globals. [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) already exists, so any code that uses it *and expects it to work per spec* might fail because it doesn't work like that. Much worse, it might not even throw an exception but silently not do what it should and you might not notice for months.

Comment: Yeah contributes is a string, and replaceAll does work without any problem, it is just about replaceLast which will not work. I even renamed replaceAll and it did work as well

Comment: "*and replaceAll does work without any problem*" because it is a regular method on strings, as I pointed out above. The question is, have you loaded your own overloads? Evidence suggests "no". But you've not supplied a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Or barring that, give a link to a properly configured web IDE project that demonstrates your issue.  Right now it's not obvious why your prototype modification isn't working at runtime.  Aside: I assume you know that adding your own non-spec-compliant methods to `String.prototype` is A Bad Idea, especially ones whose names conflict with existing methods.